# Javascript click function img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript which displays images from style and css.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("div[style]").click(function() {
        $("#full-wrap-new").css("background-image", $(this).css("background-image"));
    });
});
</script>

<div id="colors">
<div style="background-image:url(/images/style/whatcan.jpg); width:200px; height:150px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background-image:url(/images/art/art.jpg); width:200px; height:150px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background-image:url(/images/beauty/beauty.jpg); width:200px; height:150px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background-image:url(/images/careers/career.jpg); width:200px; height:150px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to change the script to use img rather than css how do i change this following line of script.

```
$("#full-wrap-new").css("background-image", $(this).css("background-image"));
```

This is what i have so far but i have no idea how to change it to img

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("div.ri").click(function() {
        $("#full-wrap-new").css("background-image", $(this).css("background-image"));
    });
});
</script>

<div id="colors">
<div class="ri"><img src="/images/style/whatcan.jpg"/></div>
<div class="ri"><img src="/images/art/art.jpg"/></div>
<div class="ri"><img src="/images/beauty/beauty.jpg"/></div>
<div class="ri"><img src="/images/careers/career.jpg"/></div>
</div>

<div id="full-wrap-new"></div>
```

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle with your code.

Comment: Are you just trying to change your markup, or are you attempting to update your jQuery code to deal with the new markup? Will you elaborate on the exact nature of the problem you encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you trying to do this:

```
$(function () {
    $("div.ri").click(function() {
        $("#full-wrap-new").html($(this).find("img").clone());
    });
});
```

Try it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBudB/1/) (change the sources so you can see something)